# Google Spreadsheet Comments

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet with several boxes with the little orange triangle indicating a comment associated with that cell.  Unfortunately, I haven't made any comments, so cannot delete these boxes.  How do I go about clearing these cells without deleting everything and starting over?

Comment: Where did the comments come from? Is this a shared spreadsheet? Is it copied from someone else's spreadsheet?

Comment: Comments, as opposed to notes, can be made by multiple people. If this is a shared spreadsheet you may not be able to delete them.

Comment: I'm not sure where the comments are coming from. The sheet is only shared with one other person, and he is having the same problem only worse. Both sheets show a different number of comments, all of which appear to be empty. 

I've tried adding a comment with the intention of deleting it, but any square with the phantom comment flag won't allow me to add a new comment to it. 

If I delete a row (or a column) containing the phantom comments, they disappear. Reinserting the column (or row) causes the comments to reappear.

Comment: If I were you, I'd start with a new spreadsheet and copy the data over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Per the Google Drive Help page](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=known_issues.cs):

> We've received reports of users seeing comment indicators on cells in which no comments exist, as well as comment indicators in the incorrect cell after a sheet is resorted, duplicated, or amended by copy/paste.
>
> Our team is aware of the issue and working on a fix. As a workaround, if you notice out-of-place comment indicators, simply refresh the spreadsheet. All comment indicators should appear in the correct cells again.

Following these instructions, I tried simply hitting the refresh button and all of the phantom comments disappeared. I guess sometimes the easiest solution is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you should be able to right-click one of the cells, choose `Insert comment`, then click the delete link. After you confirm the comment(s) should be gone.

Comment: I'm not sure where the comments are coming from. The sheet is only shared with one other person, and he is having the same problem only worse.  Both sheets show a different number of comments, all of which appear to be empty.

Comment: I've tried adding a comment with the intention of deleting it, but any square with the phantom comment flag won't allow me to add a new comment to it.

Comment: If I delete a row (or a column) containing the phantom comments, they disappear.  Reinserting the column (or row) causes the comments to reappear.